# Sentences which could be read as meaning its opposite as well

Tags: meaning, verbs

I recently saw this headline on the Granuaid front page: *Havelange 'paid millions in bribes'*

In this case, Havelange **received** the bribes, but the headline still works. It struck me that its naive meaning would be the opposite i.e. Havelange umm.. **paid** the bribes to someone else.

Is there a term for this sort of double-loading where a sentence could represent a proposition and also its converse? Any other examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Other examples? Oh, yes, some folks have [entire collections](http://littlecalamity.tripod.com/Text/Newspaper.html) of them, particularly the more humorous ones.  Some are ambiguous, but others are just ill-advised word pairings, like, [_One-armed man applauds kindness of strangers_](http://www.pleated-jeans.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/funny-headline12.jpeg).

Comment: Many of those stem from polysemous words. My example, I believe, is made possible because English has two voices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Amphiboly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibology)** is used to refer to such grammatical structures.